# Android Pattern Logic

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZCmm.png)

This can anyone explain me this logic.

Here the answer I get is the actual answer which I want but I want to know the proper working flow behind this pattern.

THANKS

Comment: Don't post images of code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
 Your for loop will run for 10 times from 0-9.
then inside your for loop you inserted the color.
then your if condition states that when there is even place print white 
else black.(i%2==0 means even)
```

Comment: please check the result sir.
I got ( "black" , "white" , "white" , "black" ) and not ("black" , "white" ,"black" , "white" )

so I want understand that how it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i%2==0)
{
    print"Black"
} else { 
    print"White"
}
```